# Getting "Variable might not initialized error"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating function for Sqlite database and getting "variable might not initialized" error. I am trying to store sqlite data in string array.

```
public String[] gettitle()
  {
          String title[];
          String s = "select Title from User_DB;";
          SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(s,null);
          int a = 0;
          while(cursor.moveToNext())
          {

              title[a] = cursor.getString(0);
              a++;
          }
          return title;
  }
```

it says title[] is not initialized but I dont understand why. I clearly initialized it.

Comment: `String[] title = new String[1000];` would be an initialisation (`= ...`). Do not forget `return Arrays.copyOf(title, a);` and `while(cursor.moveToNext() && a < title.length)`

Comment: I dont get it. Can you please explain    what should I do in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You *declare* `title`. Allowed C language style is `String title[]`. In java one keeps the type expression together: `String[] title;`

   ```
      String[] title;
   ```

   This variable is *uninitialized*, reserves a memory slot for an array object, but the memory is not filled, initialized; it contains garbage. At its first usage of `title` the compiler issues an error.

   In contrast class *fields* are initialized automatically by a default: here `null`, but for other types `0`, `false`, `0.0` and so on.
2. Initialize the variable: give it an initial value.

   For arrays that means set an array object. Arrays are fixed length, cannot grow, and thus:

   ```
    String[] title;
    title = new String[10];
   ```

   Or shorter:

   ```
    String[] title = new String[10];
   ```

   Like *fields* also *array elements* are initialized with defaults, `null`.

   Note you initialized `a`: `int a = 0;`.
3. Now you can use the array object through the variable:

   ```
          title[a] = cursor.getString(0);
   ```

   This was the point where the compiler saw the usage of a variable that still did not have a value.

So the code becomes:

```
public String[] loadTitles() {
    String[] titles = new String[100];
    String sql = "select Title from User_DB";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    int a = 0;
    try (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null)) {
        while (a < titles.length && cursor.moveToNext()) {
            titles[a] = cursor.getString(0);
            a++;
        }
    } // Calls cursor.close();
    return Arrays.copyOf(titles, a);
}
```

[`Array.copyOf(array, newLength)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) make copy of the original array with as new length the number of read titles.

I have added the (weird) *try-with-resources* syntax which ensures that `cursor` is closed, even on exception or return happening inside the block.